# notice Tried for 122 seconds to get a connection to scrubbed:80. Giving up

Tags: configuration, exit-relays, proxy, torsocks, connection

Getting error while sending multiple http requests through tor circuit.

```
Sep 18 17:59:13.000 [notice] New control connection opened.
Sep 18 17:59:28.000 [warn] Destination '[scrubbed]' seems to be an invalid hostname. Failing.
Sep 18 18:00:15.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $5E56738E7F97AA81DEEF59AF28494293DFBFCCDF~Backplane at 172.98.193.43. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:00:31.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $B0279A521375F3CB2AE210BDBFC645FDD2E1973A~chulak at 176.126.252.11. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:01:39.000 [notice] We tried for 65 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $379FB450010D17078B3766C2273303C358C3A442~aurora at 176.126.252.12. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:01:39.000 [notice] Tried for 122 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
Sep 18 18:01:40.000 [warn] Destination '[scrubbed]' seems to be an invalid hostname. Failing.
Sep 18 18:02:40.000 [notice] Tor has not observed any network activity for the past 127 seconds. Disabling circuit build timeout recording.
Sep 18 18:03:40.000 [notice] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up. (waiting for circuit)
Sep 18 18:03:54.000 [notice] Tor now sees network activity. Restoring circuit build timeout recording. Network was down for 200 seconds during 37 circuit attempts.
Sep 18 18:04:10.000 [warn] Destination '[scrubbed]' seems to be an invalid hostname. Failing.
Sep 18 18:04:49.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $F3B72E1EE437FE92EACF7E43D941D250290F2B71~bravopanchino at 192.195.80.10. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:05:04.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $162F7E752504C49A656FF1E9669E0B9572CE4870~Necto5 at 93.115.95.206. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:05:19.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $30C19B81981F450C402306E2E7CFB6C3F79CB6B2~Libero at 64.113.32.29. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:05:34.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $DAB96CEA61CC039A803217035293FAB32645FDDA~kree at 85.248.227.165. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:05:49.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $636E4E7D41530E064D61F57586F2F75F83271482~xerileez177 at 89.144.12.15. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:06:04.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $DA0FE8B5DD9717F52376F55885BC72E619ACD97D~heine at 51.15.53.83. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:06:19.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $7A3DD280EA4CD4DD16EF8C67B93D9BDE184D1A81~Quintex39 at 199.249.223.48. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:06:19.000 [notice] Tried for 125 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
Sep 18 18:07:05.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $21954C79058F62F8A3C1EF5E5FC16657F924711C~OxylEta at 89.45.226.28. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:07:20.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $AD9B580836C9942317E9B7664EC7B39075DEBB5B~PiratenNDS3 at 46.165.223.217. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:07:35.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $BC630CBBB518BE7E9F4E09712AB0269E9DC7D626~IPredator at 197.231.221.211. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:07:50.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $5DC945CE8FB2A37E6E2795ECD2709BB21F8714B0~Unnamed at 207.244.70.35. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:08:05.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $B84F248233FEA90CAD439F292556A3139F6E1B82~tollana at 85.248.227.164. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:08:20.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $71AB4726D830FAE776D74AEF790CF04D8E0151B4~niftycottontail at 51.15.34.210. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:08:35.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $EC116BCB80565A408CE67F8EC3FE3B0B02C3A065~orion at 94.242.246.24. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:08:35.000 [notice] Tried for 125 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
Sep 18 18:09:12.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $9C1E7D92115D431385B8CAEA6A7C15FB89CE236B~QuintexAirVPN21 at 199.249.224.40. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:09:27.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $CDA2EA326E2272C57ACB26773D7252C211795B78~niftygerbil at 51.15.70.226. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:09:42.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $734EDDC2C04B1C0184178167ABD23AE85413212F~torlesnet1 at 199.87.154.255. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:09:57.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $DAB96CEA61CC039A803217035293FAB32645FDDA~kree at 85.248.227.165. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:10:12.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $4198BD138E5E11B15B05C826B427148CED7D99FE~ParEpistemenTaksis at 163.172.101.137. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:10:27.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $734EDDC2C04B1C0184178167ABD23AE85413212F~torlesnet1 at 199.87.154.255. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:10:42.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $09FA8B4F665AD65D2C2A49870F1AA3BA8811E449~StanMarsh at 216.218.222.12. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:10:42.000 [notice] Tried for 125 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
Sep 18 18:11:42.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $FDAED15C98CFE7A416E5676F614254F78406105C~dorrisdeebrown at 192.36.27.4. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:11:57.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $68E67F1ABC55915E796E7011C8867909E74E2890~warsaw at 145.239.29.201. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:12:12.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $12D17D9F9E30FA901DE68806950A0EA278716CED~AccessNow011 at 176.10.99.205. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:12:27.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $2C539063E38B8DA96DBE742682AAD23954CDB807~kljlkjjlklkjlk at 149.202.51.88. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:12:42.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $30C19B81981F450C402306E2E7CFB6C3F79CB6B2~Libero at 64.113.32.29. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:12:57.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $311A4533F7A2415F42346A6C8FA77E6FD279594C~DigiGesTor3e2 at 178.209.42.84. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:13:12.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $9AA3FF35E7A549D2337E962333D366E102FE4D50~DigiGesTor3e1 at 178.209.42.84. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:13:12.000 [notice] Tried for 125 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
Sep 18 18:14:06.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $B771AA877687F88E6F1CA5354756DF6C8A7B6B24~niftypika at 163.172.140.123. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:14:21.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $335746A6DEB684FABDF3FC5835C3898F05C5A5A8~KyleBroflovski at 216.218.222.11. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:14:36.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $2C9C6E818CDEC876CF34627A034E7187084D8D6B~BabylonNetwork07 at 51.15.60.255. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:14:51.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $F6A358DD367B3282D6EF5824C9D45E1A19C7E815~prawksi at 192.160.102.168. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:15:08.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $1FEC860E59949E60D112FA26649CF0E32693FB4F~watchme at 163.172.212.115. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:15:23.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $74A19D86DDF63F1133B414B81F36E1F44640811F~Unnamed at 62.210.105.116. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:15:38.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $1388E7C77373197D4DB4CF406C0513D2D5847613~Andromeda1 at 195.123.212.118. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:15:38.000 [notice] Tried for 127 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
Sep 18 18:16:30.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $5CECC5C30ACC4B3DE462792323967087CC53D947~PrivacyRepublic0001 at 178.32.181.96. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:16:46.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $DAA3D3F6FDA962885072537E3F315086B003A6E3~DC225TorExitNode at 46.101.139.248. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:17:04.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $B84F248233FEA90CAD439F292556A3139F6E1B82~tollana at 85.248.227.164. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:17:20.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $AFF2FC5C6F793B6E147EB93C1897D6DDA49E54FD~Wix at 5.196.66.162. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:17:37.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $5DC945CE8FB2A37E6E2795ECD2709BB21F8714B0~Unnamed at 207.244.70.35. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:17:54.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $379FB450010D17078B3766C2273303C358C3A442~aurora at 176.126.252.12. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:17:54.000 [notice] Tried for 122 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
```

Below is the code. I am sending DNS query first and then http request over a list of websites. What can be the issue here ?

```
r = dns.resolver.Resolver()
r.nameservers = ['127.0.0.1']
r.port = 9053

with open("testWeb.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
urls = [x.strip() for x in content]


with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate(password='')
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
    temp = socket.socket
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket

    for url in urls:
        try:
            answer_tor = r.query(url)
        except Exception as e:
            print "Exception in website : " + url + " " + e.message

        try:
            req = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+url+"\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.110 Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n\r\n"
            controller.authenticate(password='')                
            # http request to tor circuit IP
            Url = (str(answer_tor[0]), 80)
            d = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
            d.connect(Url)
            d.send(req)
            tor_response = str(d.recv(12288))
            d.close()
        except Exception as e:
            ExceptionHappenedWhileExperiment.append("Exception in website : " + url + " " + e.message)
            print "Exception in website : " + url + " " + e.message
```

Comment: there's a lot going on here...like that code has some obvious problems that will cause issues and potentially exactly the issues that you're getting there, but the long and short of it is you're trying to connect to an address/addresses that exits cannot connect to (so it's likely invalid/dead)

Comment: I am catching those invalid hostname exceptions. Is this still an issue ? What should I do to work around this ?

Comment: First I'd run `SafeLogging 0` in Tor to figure out what `[scrubbed]` is, so you know where it's trying to connect to, that you should give you a pretty good idea of why it's failing.

Comment: Getting 204.86.64.169.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have port 80 open, so failing to connect seems like the expected result? http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/204.86.64.169

Comment: How can I solve the issue ? Should I force the tor circuit not to go through this IP or making a circuit manually ? I am new to this. Can you help me with this issue ?

Comment: The website you are trying to fetch is down, so Tor cannot connect. There is no "solve" except to try to request only websites that actually exist.